# Clojure/Java - pop-up window

Tags: java, clojure

Sometimes when using external libraries in Clojure, this strange windows gets opened up. It's called `clojure.main`. It looks like a new app and it has a cute little coffee mug as its icon.

Pardon my Java-land ignorance---I realize this is probably a silly question but I couldn't find it anywhere on the Internets and Googles.

What is this app doing? Why and when does it appear?

**EDIT**: Running leiningen 2, Clojure 1.3 and Noir 1.2.1. This is on OSX.

As far as I can tell, the code that is triggering this is the following function:

```
(defn make-thumbnail [filename new-filename width]
    (let [img (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read (as-file filename))
            imgtype (java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_ARGB)
            width (min (.getWidth img) width)
            height (* (/ width (.getWidth img)) (.getHeight img))
            simg (java.awt.image.BufferedImage. width height imgtype)
            g (.createGraphics simg)]
        (.drawImage g img 0 0 width height nil)
        (.dispose g)
        (javax.imageio.ImageIO/write simg "png" (as-file new-filename))))
```

Comment: Can you post some code, like your project.clj and your core.clj (or the main Clojure -- .clj -- application file? What platform is this running on? This almost sounds like you're running on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might have something to do with [AWT not running in headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/). Have you tried setting the `java.awt.headless` system property to `true`?

Comment: Fixed by adding `:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-Djava.awt.headless=true"] ` to project.clj. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathon What kind of application would you have to write to get this? I didn't come from a Java background, so I've been writing pretty much native Clojure with a few Java calls.

Comment: I think any server-side application that does image processing pretty much needs this directive. That's the only time I've had to use it.

Comment: I also had this same popup window problem when first initializing JNA (Java Native Interface), and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as `Honza Pokorny` said, add `"-Djava.awt.headless=true"` to :`jvm-opts` in project.clj

It should look like this:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-Djava.awt.headless=true"]
```